# Snowflake float type column out of range error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I got Numeric value out of range error when trying to insert two values into a Float type column.

```
create or replace table num_test(float_num float); -- create table and column
INSERT INTO num_test (float_num)VALUES (1.0528618730874378E10), (-3.694822225952521E-13);
```

The error i got shows: "Numeric value '10528618730.874378' is out of range."

But when i try to insert these two values separately, it work fine.

```
INSERT INTO num_test (float_num)VALUES (1.0528618730874378E10); -- ok
INSERT INTO num_test (float_num)VALUES (-3.694822225952521E-13); -- ok
```

I couldn't see any out of range issues on the snowflake [document](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#float-float4-float8) for the values I tried to insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess what the problem was, it would be that "the guess of the "type" based on the first value in the VALUES is smaller than the type of the second value".

So if we just try and select those values with zero target problems:

```
select column1, system$typeof(column1) 
from VALUES
    (1.0528618730874378E10),
    (-3.694822225952521E-13);
```

triggers.

> Numeric value '10528618730.874378' is out of range

One at a time we get:

| COLUMN1 | SYSTEM$TYPEOF(COLUMN1) |
| --- | --- |
| -0.0000000000003695 | NUMBER(29,28)[SB16] |

| COLUMN1 | SYSTEM$TYPEOF(COLUMN1) |
| --- | --- |
| 10,528,618,730.874378 | NUMBER(17,6)[SB8] |

So sure enough the two random "numbers" are cast to two different types, and these are deemed "too different". Thus my guess was correct.

### What to do about this:

So we inline cast them:

```
select column1, system$typeof(column1) 
from VALUES
    (1.0528618730874378E10::double),
    (-3.694822225952521E-13::double)
    ;
```

we get

| COLUMN1 | SYSTEM$TYPEOF(COLUMN1) |
| --- | --- |
| 10,528,618,730.8744 | FLOAT[DOUBLE] |
| -0.0000000000003695 | FLOAT[DOUBLE] |

so the values are safe if we first tell the DB what they are, and avoid the auto guessing code.

thus in your context:

```
INSERT INTO num_test (float_num)VALUES
    (1.0528618730874378E10::double),
    (-3.694822225952521E-13::double)
    ;
```

| number of rows inserted |
| --- |
| 2 |

Comment: Thanks Simeon for you answer, I didn't know Snowflake is doing auto guessing even when I defined the column type to be Float. Is there any way to insert those values without casting? I'm writing values to Snwoflake using JDBC with prepared statements. It's also acceptable if the data is stored in some lower-precision form.

Comment: If the jdbc the data should already be typed. The auto guess is just the sql parser. Which jdbc should not be anywhere near.

Comment: I think my issue was that i was using `prepareStatement(String sql_text)` to create the `preparedStatement` object, and those values were already included as part of the `sql_text` string and get executed directly. I should probably modify the code to use `setDouble` or `setFloat` method on the `preparedStatement` object.